# GSiteCrawler Server-Test showing error?

Tags: php, redirect, seo

In this code I am giving redirection $searchLink

```
$urlCity = strtolower($_COOKIE['UserCityName']);
 $searchLink = '/properties-in-'.$urlCity.'.php'; 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $searchLink)
 {
    Header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
    Header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$searchLink);   
 }
```

But in GSiteCrawler Server-Test showing error it showing

```
'http://legacy.com/properties-in-.php' 
Result code: 200 (OK / OK)

'http://legacy.com/properties-in-chennai.php'  like this it should come
```

How i can fix this

Comment: I doubt that code really sends a valid redirection. Not if there is not some more code you did not post here. All you do is to output a path, not more. Especially since you unconditionally exit() your script...

Comment: only this code i am using for redirection

Comment: As said: no, that is not a valid redirection.

Comment: Well, look at your code! The redirection headers are fine, but the execution never actually gets there. You `exit()` before. All you do is `print()` a path. Certainly that gives a return code 200, since that output is a valid text page.

Comment: ya i am sorry its a mistake

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23137/discussion-between-arkascha-and-athi)

Comment: Ok, looks better without that debug output :-).
Now let's look at that robots result:
'http://legacy.com/properties-in-.php'
Looks like a fine url, except that there is no location in it. The reason simply is that there is no COOKIE sent when the robot connects. Where should it have the cookie from? Robots don't handle cookies.

Comment: any other method i can fix this

Comment: What is a bug, that robots don't send cookies? That certainly is not a bug. Why should they handle cookies? What content should that cookie contain? Which city in your case? Where should that content come from? I'd say that test simply makes no sense for a robot crawling your site. You don't do any form of error handling but instead rely on whatever the request provides. That is bad design. Before using that cookies value you ahve to check if what it contains actually is what you expect! In case of a robot: check if that value is empty (no cookie specified at all)!

Comment: ok fine so before that i want to check cookie value whether it set or not